# Colour region by some property

Tags: graphics, geometry

I have some circles placed at random within a region (here, the region is a circle-circle intersection).

```
pts1 = RandomPoint[
   ImplicitRegion[
    EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, 0] < 1 && 
     EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, {2.5, 0}] < 2, {x, y}], 3];
pts2 = RandomPoint[
   ImplicitRegion[
    EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, 0] < 2 && 
     EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, {2.5, 0}] < 1, {x, y}], 3];
Graphics[Prepend[
  Join[Circle[#, 1] & /@ pts1, Disk[#, 0.01] & /@ pts1, 
   Disk[#, 0.01] & /@ pts2], {Circle[{0, 0}, 1], Circle[{2.5, 0}, 1], 
   Circle[{0, 0}, 2], Circle[{2.5, 0}, 2], Opacity[0.4]}], 
 ImageSize -> Full]
```

Each circle covers some portion of another circle-circle intersection, as in this picture:

[image]

The regions in the right "lens" (circle-circle intersection) which are covered by 3 circles are in deep blue, by 2 circles in light blue and by 1 in yellow. The remaining region is left white.
This is done with Paintbrush.

Can I get Mathematica to colour the continuum of points automatically, like this, with $n$ colours if there are $n$ points in `pts1`?

It appears easy to do this with a `Plot` of function, and then `ColorFunction`, but with some property of a set of points in Graphics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dsk1 = Disk[{0, 0}, 1];
dsk2 = Disk[{2.5, 0}, 1];

n = 3;

SeedRandom[11]

pts = RandomPoint[ImplicitRegion[EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, 0] < 1 && 
     EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, {2.5, 0}] < 2, {x, y}], n];

dsks = Disk[#, 1] & /@ pts;

g1 = Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Gray], dsks, 
   EdgeForm[{Thick, Purple}], dsk1,  EdgeForm[{Thick, Cyan}], dsk2, 
   PointSize[Large], Point @ pts}]
```

[image]

Construct `RegionMemberFunction`s using the disks:

```
{rmf1, rmf2} = RegionMember /@ {dsk1, dsk2};

rmfs = RegionMember /@ dsks;
```

Define a predicate function `numDisks[k, rfs][{x, y}]` using [`BooleanCountingFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanCountingFunction.html)  that gives `True` when the point `{x,y}` lies in in `dsk1` or in`dsk2` and satisfies exactly `k` ($k = 1, 2, \ldots, n$) of predicates `rfs`:

```
ClearAll[numDisks]
numDisks[k_, rfs_][{x_, y_}] := (rmf1[{x, y}] || rmf2[{x, y}]) && 
   BooleanConvert @ BooleanCountingFunction[{k}, Length @ rfs] @@ 
     Through[rfs @ {x, y}]
```

Use `numDisks` to define n `ImplicitRegion`s and use them with `RegionPlot`:

```
irs = ImplicitRegion[numDisks[#, rmfs][{x, y}], {x, y}] & /@ Range[n];

rp = RegionPlot[Evaluate @ irs, PlotStyle -> 97, PlotLegends -> Range[n]]
```

[image]

```
Show[rp, g1, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

For `n = 5` we get

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Proof of concept with 3 points (nothing automatic):

```
pts1 = RandomPoint[
   ImplicitRegion[
    EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, 0] < 1 && 
     EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, {2.5, 0}] < 2, {x, y}], 3];
pts2 = RandomPoint[
   ImplicitRegion[
    EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, 0] < 2 && 
     EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, {2.5, 0}] < 1, {x, y}], 3];
c1 = Disk[#, 1] & /@ pts1;
circ1 = Region[Disk[{0, 0}, 1]];
circ2 = Region[Disk[{2.5, 0}, 1]];

(* 3 circles intersection *)

R3 = ImplicitRegion[({x, y} \[Element] circ2 && {x, y} \[Element] 
      c1[[1]] && {x, y} \[Element] c1[[2]] && {x, y} \[Element] 
      c1[[3]]), {x, y}];
bR3 = ImplicitRegion[{x, y} \[Element] circ1 && {x, y} \[Element] 
     c1[[1]] && {x, y} \[Element] c1[[2]] && {x, y} \[Element] 
     c1[[3]], {x, y}];

(* 2 circle intersection *)

R21 = ImplicitRegion[{x, y} \[Element] 
     circ2 && (({x, y} \[Element] c1[[1]] && {x, y} \[Element] 
         c1[[2]]) || ({x, y} \[Element] c1[[1]] && {x, y} \[Element] 
         c1[[3]]) || ({x, y} \[Element] c1[[2]] && {x, y} \[Element] 
         c1[[3]] )), {x, y}];
bR21 = ImplicitRegion[{x, y} \[Element] 
     circ1 && (({x, y} \[Element] c1[[1]] && {x, y} \[Element] 
         c1[[2]]) || ({x, y} \[Element] c1[[1]] && {x, y} \[Element] 
         c1[[3]]) || ({x, y} \[Element] c1[[2]] && {x, y} \[Element] 
         c1[[3]] )), {x, y}];

(* 1 circle intersection *)

RY = ImplicitRegion[{x, y} \[Element] 
     circ2 && ({x, y} \[Element] c1[[1]] \[Xor] {x, y} \[Element] 
       c1[[2]] \[Xor] {x, y} \[Element] c1[[3]]), {x, y}];
bRY = ImplicitRegion[{x, y} \[Element] 
     circ1 && ({x, y} \[Element] c1[[1]] \[Xor] {x, y} \[Element] 
       c1[[2]] \[Xor] {x, y} \[Element] c1[[3]]), {x, y}];

(* Region plots *)
RY2 = RegionPlot[RY, PlotStyle -> Yellow];
RP = RegionPlot[R21, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0, 1, 1]]];
RP3 = RegionPlot[R3, PlotStyle -> Blue];

bRY2 = RegionPlot[bRY, PlotStyle -> Yellow];
bRP = RegionPlot[bR21, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0, 1, 1]];
bRP3 = RegionPlot[bR3, PlotStyle -> Blue];

d1 = Graphics[Disk[#, 0.01] & /@ pts1];
d3 = Graphics[Disk[#, 0.01] & /@ pts2];

gr = Graphics[
   Prepend[Join[Circle[#, 1] & /@ pts1], {Circle[{0, 0}, 1], 
     Circle[{2.5, 0}, 1], Circle[{0, 0}, 2], Circle[{2.5, 0}, 2], 
     Opacity[0.4]}], ImageSize -> Full];

Show[gr, RY2, RP, RP3, bRY2, bRP, bRP3, d1, d3, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: graphic]